# Download SpriteKit atlas into Documents folder

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit, atlas

We are developing a game that have a lot of image assets and we want to keep the app size under 30MB so decided to download images within a zip file.
The first scene have 50 SKSpriteNode object and 426 images for textures and animations and we cannot create texture atlas because our images are not in the bundle.
From iOS8 we have `[SKTextureAtlas atlasWithDictionary:]` that can compile atlasc files from images that aren't in the bundle resources but we have to support iOS7 too.
When we load 426 images with `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]` and `[SKTexture textureWithImage:textureImage]` methods our app shut down because the large memory usage.

Code:

```
for (int i=0; i <= numImages-1; i++) {
    NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"texture_%05d", i];
    SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:ImagePath(textureName)];
    [frames addObject:texture];
}
```

And after:

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction animateWithTextures:frames timePerFrame:kAnimationFrameTime resize:YES restore:YES];
[node runAction:action withKey:kAnimationActionKey];
```

ImagePath macro returns with the absolute path for the given image in the Documents directory.

Is there any best practice to load large amount of images for animation from Documents directory in SpriteKit?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a loading screen and some kind of loop? Possibly write the loop to not use up too much memory. If it's written right, it shouldn't take up that much memory... possibly some code to show would help?

Comment: Thanks, modified the original question

Comment: The main problem thats I have a lot of images and SKTexture malloc too much memory:

`572.05 MB      92.2% +[SKTexture textureWithImage:]`

Comment: Your posted code does almost nothing in highlighting any potential issues. If you want people to help you, post all the relevant code regarding your issue. From your memory consumption, I would guess you are keeping all those UIImage objects alive in your code somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure you're clearing your frames array? It might be keeping the textures alive.

Comment: I read images like this:
`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];`
I don't keep frames array, the method `textureWithImage:` allocate a lot of memory because I have 40 images for an animation with 1320x1320 dimension.

According to images memory usage:
width x height x bitrate = memory usage  in bytes
1320 x 1320 x 4 = 6.9 MB to read an image and because this is an animation it will be 6.9 * 40 = 276 MB.

What can I do with that?

Comment: There's not much you can do about that. If possible, decrease the bit depth of your images and nil out all image objects as soon as possible.

Comment: There are a lot of game in the AppStore that download the images of a level after run the app, I think there would be a better solution to manage this.

Comment: I'm sure there are but I doubt a lot of them download 276 MB worth of images. That's a lot any which way you look at it and could potentially use up a substantial amount of a user's data plan too. I would certainly not be happy if an app started doing that on my phone.

Comment: The size of the downloaded zip file is ~10 MB...

Comment: Can't you create and upload the texture atlas file and have your app download that directly? Seems to be wasteful to have the app do something that you could have done in advance.

Comment: I can create and upload atlasc files but I can't use them outside the app bundle just over iOS 8